# React Native With Redux Data Flow

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I recently ran into an issue with React Native and Redux while implementing OAuth which provoked some amount of head-scratching. The scenario is as follows:

- I use Redux in my React Native app
- The user logs in and the refresh token and access token are stored.
- In an action creator for another component the user needs to call a rest endpoint with the short-lived access token.
- However, for every call, the user needs to call a service method like `getAccessToken()` which will always return a valid access token, and if the tokens are expiring it will renew them and will update the store.

The data flow in Redux is **strictly unidirectional**, meaning, the user calls the action creator, which in turn will call the reducer, which will change the state in the store and the component will re-render with the new state. However, I cannot possiblly bind the state of my component to the access token; every time the user wants to make a Rest call she should call `getAccessToken()` to make sure that she receives a valid token before sending.

Any suggestions as to how to implement this using **React Native and Redux**? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How to do it in your way:

1. Call `getAccessToken().then(token => myOtherCall(token))`
2. After the second call succeeds dispatch two actions, one to the corresponding reducer with the result and another one saving the new token.

How I would do it:

Using [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), I would setup a loop that refreshes the token every X seconds. If a request fails because of 401 status code, I would refresh the token and retry the api call.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into redux-saga for sure. Another question, would it be an acceptable approach to both dispatch and return a value from an action creator? I havent seen it done before, and am wondering if its an anti pattern. Thanks.

Comment: It's fine to dispatch multiple actions in an action creator using redux-thunk https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: multiple actions, sure. what about this:  { dispatch({...}); return result;}

Comment: Depending on your exact case - yes